# loop create from file

Tags: shell-script

I have a file(test) It contains 
two columns and two lines

```
pippo mm

pluto tt
```

I would like to create directory,owner and create password 
I do some think like that

```
while IFS= read a b; do
mkdir -p /srv/ftp/$a
chown -R ftp:ftp /srv/ftp/$a/
passwd $a $b
done <  /test
```

I expect to have 2 directory `pippo` and `pluto` under `/srv/ftp/` but i have only `pippo`

thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your file `test` have blanks lines?

Answer (score 0):

You 'll want `IFS` to be a space, it should be like this :

```
while IFS=" " read a b; do
mkdir -p /srv/ftp/$a
chown -R ftp:ftp /srv/ftp/$a/
passwd $a $b
done <  /test
```

Comment: unfortunately no I still have only Pluto not  pluto and also pippo

Comment: Btw, what is `$b` supposed to be?

Comment: is the password mm 
I expect  create director pippo set password for user pippo and also create director pluto  set password for user pluto ecc ....

Comment: @Macro: Does your file `test` have blanks lines ?

Comment: You can't pass the password to `passwd` command's arguments. So `$b` make no sense. Your test file should have only 1 column - the username

Comment: even if I canceled the second column but i still have only pluto

Answer (score 0):

You have a file containing two space separated fields, the username and the password:

> ```
> pippo mm
> pluto tt
> ```

You can use a script like this to process the file, creating the user account and the corresponding directory:

```
ftpuid=$(getent passwd ftp | cut -d: -f3)
if test -z "$ftpuid"; then echo "No ftp account" >&2; exit 1; fi

while read -r user password
do
    test -z "$user" && continue
    echo "Creating account for $user, with home /srv/ftp/$user" >&2
    useradd -d /srv/ftp/"$user" -M -N -g ftp -o -u "$ftpuid" "$user"
    mkdir -m700 -p /srv/ftp/"$user"
    chown "$ftpuid":ftp /srv/ftp/"$user"
    test -n "$password" && ( echo "$password"; echo "$password" ) | passwd -q "$user" 2>/dev/null
done < file.txt
```

There are other options for settings passwords such as `chpasswd`, but I don't believe that this appropriate here.

Comment: unfortunately no I still have only Pluto not pluto and also pippo

Comment: @Marco the example data file and code I have provided here works fine on my test machine. I'll add some simple debug; please try it again with that line added.